# POWER BI --> R Script: Enable R Script from Anaconda

Tags: r, anaconda, powerbi

I've been trying for a long time to enable R Scripts from Anaconda on PowerBi.
This is the error I get:

> Error Message: A problem occurred while processing your R script.
> Here are the technical details:  Running the R script encountered the
> following error:
>
> Failed to retrieve error code string from System ->317 Double-check
> that R is installed correctly on your machine.

This is what I have tried so far:

- Even that I get no errors while selecting the folder on PowerBi Options, using anaconda folder location [C:\Users\santiago\Anaconda3\envs...] doesn't seems to work.
- I thought the problem was because R was installed by Anaconda inside anaconda environments. So I installed R using anaconda, but in an external environment [C:\Temp\R_Environment\envs\lib\R]. But of course I get the same error every time I run a simple 'hello world'.

Is there anyone there who has been able to instal R from anaconda and using it on PowerBi?

Answer (score 1):

The key for working with a conda environment is that you have to **activate it before you can use it** in an application. Power BI won't do that for you, so you have to do that in a command shell:

```
conda activate r_env
PBIDesktop.exe
```

Make sure your PBIDesktop.exe is on the path or navigate to the installation folder. You still need to configure your R home directory in the Power BI Options for R scripting.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Unfortunately I can't find PBIDesktop.exe, sounds silly, but I have installed PBI from Microsoft Store, and apparently there is no executable file for PowerBI.